# SageMaker batch transform not loading CSV correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a batch transform job that us uploading data from a CSV. The CSV is formatted as such

"joe annes rifle accesories discount"

"cute puppies for sale"

"Two dudes talk about sports"

"Smith & Wesson M&P 500 review"

"Glock vs 1911 handgun"

My code for creating the batch transform is below

```py
elec_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    model_data='s3://some_path/binary-model', 
    role=role, 
    entry_point='torchserve_.py',
    source_dir='source_dir',
    transformers_version="4.17.0",
    pytorch_version='1.10.2',
    py_version='py38'
)

nl_detector = elec_model.transformer(
    instance_type = 'ml.g4dn.xlarge',
    strategy="MultiRecord",
    assemble_with="Line",
    output_path = "s3://some_path/trash_output"
)

nl_detector.transform(
    "s3://some_bucket/trash",
    content_type="text/csv",
    split_type="Line"
)
```

When I run this code instead of the batch job taking the CSV and breaking up the examples with every space, which is what

`split_type="Line"`

is telling the algorithm to do, but instead it just ingests all of the sentences in the above CSV, and outputs 1 probability.

When I print the input payload it looks like this EDIT: all three sentences are printed at once.

```
"joe annes rifle accesories discount"

2022-10-26T21:03:04,265 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 

"cute puppies for sale"

2022-10-26T21:03:04,265 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 

"Two dudes talk about sports"

2022-10-26T21:03:04,265 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle
```

Where each sentence is an inference example, and is separated by this statement

```
2022-10-26T21:03:04,265 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle
```

So it seems like sagemaker is separating the inference examples. But when I try and pass these sentences into a huggingface tokenizer, the tokenizer tokenizes them like they are one inference example, when they should be 3 distinct inference examples. I've also tried printing and or returning the above object at an indice, hoping the object pointed at an indice would return a sentence. But it instead just returns a character, which seems to confirm the object above with three sentences is treated as one string instead of three

EDIT 1:

Here is the code for my inference logic torch_serve_.py

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import logging
import json

import torch
from sagemaker_inference import content_types, decoder

import subprocess
#subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'transformers'])

from transformers import ElectraTokenizer



def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Load the model for inference
    """

    model= torch.load(model_dir + "/arms_ammunition.pth")
    model.eval()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)
    
    #use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    #if use_cuda:
    #    model.cuda()
    ##return model.to(device)
    return model


    
def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    """
    Apply model to the incoming request
    """

    print('listy!!!!!!!!!:   ', input_data)


    tokenizer = ElectraTokenizer.from_pretrained('google/electra-base-discriminator')
    sm = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=2)
    
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    #model.to(device)
    #model.eval()
    encoded_inputs = tokenizer(input_data, max_length=220, padding = 'longest', truncation = True)
    print('encoded_inputs', encoded_inputs)
    tokened_words = encoded_inputs['input_ids']
    #print('tokened_wordssssssss:   ', tokened_words)
    attention_mask = encoded_inputs['attention_mask']
    #print('attention_maskkkkkkkk:   ', attention_mask)
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(torch.tensor(tokened_words).unsqueeze(0).to(device), torch.tensor(attention_mask).unsqueeze(0).to(device))
        #print('mmooddeell!!!!!!!!!  ', model)
        #probs = sm(outputs.logits)
        probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs.logits, 1)
     
        return probs
        #return model(input_data.float()).numpy()[0]
    
    
def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    """
    Deserialize and prepare the prediction input
    """
    print("type of jawn!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", type(request_body))
    print('request_content_type', request_content_type)
    print('requ_body', request_body)
    return request_body
    
        
        
def output_fn(prediction_output, accept):
    print("prediction_output.tolist()", prediction_output)
    return prediction_output.tolist()
    #return json.dumps(prediction_output.tolist())
```

EDIT 2: SNIPPET OF LOGS BELOW

```
2022-10-27T19:52:00,401 [INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Model model loaded io_fd=0242a9fffefeff83-0000001c-00000001-1c705d0aba004d53-1d21a7ab
2022-10-27T19:52:00,402 [INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 4800
2022-10-27T19:52:00,404 [WARN ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - attachIOStreams() threadName=W-model-1
2022-10-27T19:52:00,406 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - type of jawn!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! <class 'str'>
2022-10-27T19:52:00,407 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - request_content_type text/csv
2022-10-27T19:52:00,407 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - requ_body "New Delhi\, June 04 (ANI): Food Safety and Standards Association of India (FSSAI) CEO Yudhvir Singh Malik on Thursday said that the reports submitted by Delhi and Kerala are fully authentic while that submitted by Goa was inappropriate. He also said that Goa food officials are asked to submit their proper report in 2-3 days time. Further\, Malik said that the food business manufacturer should have their own plans for checking of their products so as to avoid such lapses. He also said that the food safety commissioners are asked to not only focus on Nestle but also to pick up samples from other manufacturers."
2022-10-27T19:52:00,408 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "MW 328 अश्लील फोटोचा धाक दाखवून विवाहितेवर सलग 2 दिवस अत्याचार | औरंगाबाद |\\n\\nGAON MAJHA NEWS is one of Most Watched Marathi News channel. \\n\\nHere you can watch live Marathi news\, breaking news\, politics news\, latest news\, entertainment news\, tech news\, auto news\, lifestyle news & more. TODAYS MARATHI NEWS\, Trending News\,  RECENT NEWS\, CURRENT NEWS\,   WORLD NEWS\, DAILY NEWS\, latest news\, Marathi news\, Latest Marathi News\, Latest News in Marathi\, Marathi news live\, News Marathi\, Breaking News in Marathi\, Live Marathi News\, News in Marathi\, ताज्या मराठी बातम्या \, Marathi Batmya.\\n\\n\\nSUBSCRIBE TO GAON MAJHA NEWS :- \\nFacebook page:-\\nhttps://www.facebook.com/gaonmajhanews/\\n\\nTwitter:-\\nhttps://twitter.com/gaonmajhanews1\\n\\nGaonmajha  Official Website:-\\nhttp://www.gaonmajha.in/\\n\\nGoogle+:-\\nhttps://plus.google.com/u/0/\\n\\nYoutube:-\\nhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbVX89IreHNyjcHuDTIqicQ?view_as=subscriber\\n\\n\\nStay tuned for all the breaking news in Marathi  with GAON MAJHA NEWS!"
2022-10-27T19:52:00,409 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "Subscribe our channel for More Video & Updates: https://go./j07htL\\r\\n\\r\\nFollow us on\\r\\nFacebook : https://www.facebook.com/gstv.news\\r\\nTwitter : https://twitter.com/gstv_news\\r\\n#gujaratinews #gstv #gstvnews  #GSTVLIVE #gujaratinewslive #gujaratinewspaper #gujaratinews2020 \\r\\n#gujaratinewscoronavirustoday #covind19\\r\\n#GujaratSamacharLiveTV #GujaratSamachar"
2022-10-27T19:52:00,409 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "Minutes count when you're having a heart attack. But it took the Chicago Fire Department more than 40 minutes to get a 56-year-old man to a hospital for help. CBS 2's Pam Zekman reports."
2022-10-27T19:52:00,409 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "Margie Pargie & The Yoga Hangout SRQ kicked off the Sexy Transformation Challenge with a visit to local boxing gym\, Uppercut Boxing & Fitness. We joined Aaron Jaco\, Pro Boxer and owner of the gym for a kickass\, heart pumping\, beast mode workout. The atmosphere\, intense yet playful\, kept everyone pushing hard until the last minute. Traditional elements of boxing mixed with plyometrics\, weight training\, and high intensity cardio blended for a solid 500-1000 calorie burn session. If you are looking for results\, a supportive community\, and a workout built for the most hardcore\, you should visit Aaron! He will show you all the moves to be your sexiest self!\\n\\nwww.aerialyogaschool.com to enter the Sexy Transformation Challenge \\nwww.uppercutboxingsarasota.com for info about taking Aaron Jaco's class"
2022-10-27T19:52:00,409 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-10-27T19:52:00,410 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - listy!!!!!!!!!:    "New Delhi\, June 04 (ANI): Food Safety and Standards Association of India (FSSAI) CEO Yudhvir Singh Malik on Thursday said that the reports submitted by Delhi and Kerala are fully authentic while that submitted by Goa was inappropriate. He also said that Goa food officials are asked to submit their proper report in 2-3 days time. Further\, Malik said that the food business manufacturer should have their own plans for checking of their products so as to avoid such lapses. He also said that the food safety commissioners are asked to not only focus on Nestle but also to pick up samples from other manufacturers."
2022-10-27T19:52:00,410 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "MW 328 अश्लील फोटोचा धाक दाखवून विवाहितेवर सलग 2 दिवस अत्याचार | औरंगाबाद |\\n\\nGAON MAJHA NEWS is one of Most Watched Marathi News channel. \\n\\nHere you can watch live Marathi news\, breaking news\, politics news\, latest news\, entertainment news\, tech news\, auto news\, lifestyle news & more. TODAYS MARATHI NEWS\, Trending News\,  RECENT NEWS\, CURRENT NEWS\,   WORLD NEWS\, DAILY NEWS\, latest news\, Marathi news\, Latest Marathi News\, Latest News in Marathi\, Marathi news live\, News Marathi\, Breaking News in Marathi\, Live Marathi News\, News in Marathi\, ताज्या मराठी बातम्या \, Marathi Batmya.\\n\\n\\nSUBSCRIBE TO GAON MAJHA NEWS :- \\nFacebook page:-\\nhttps://www.facebook.com/gaonmajhanews/\\n\\nTwitter:-\\nhttps://twitter.com/gaonmajhanews1\\n\\nGaonmajha  Official Website:-\\nhttp://www.gaonmajha.in/\\n\\nGoogle+:-\\nhttps://plus.google.com/u/0/\\n\\nYoutube:-\\nhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbVX89IreHNyjcHuDTIqicQ?view_as=subscriber\\n\\n\\nStay tuned for all the breaking news in Marathi  with GAON MAJHA NEWS!"
2022-10-27T19:52:00,411 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "Subscribe our channel for More Video & Updates: https://go/j07htL\\r\\n\\r\\nFollow us on\\r\\nFacebook : https://www.facebook.com/gstv.news\\r\\nTwitter : https://twitter.com/gstv_news\\r\\n#gujaratinews #gstv #gstvnews  #GSTVLIVE #gujaratinewslive #gujaratinewspaper #gujaratinews2020 \\r\\n#gujaratinewscoronavirustoday #covind19\\r\\n#GujaratSamacharLiveTV #GujaratSamachar"
2022-10-27T19:52:00,412 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "Minutes count when you're having a heart attack. But it took the Chicago Fire Department more than 40 minutes to get a 56-year-old man to a hospital for help. CBS 2's Pam Zekman reports."
2022-10-27T19:52:00,412 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - "Margie Pargie & The Yoga Hangout SRQ kicked off the Sexy Transformation Challenge with a visit to local boxing gym\, Uppercut Boxing & Fitness. We joined Aaron Jaco\, Pro Boxer and owner of the gym for a kickass\, heart pumping\, beast mode workout. The atmosphere\, intense yet playful\, kept everyone pushing hard until the last minute. Traditional elements of boxing mixed with plyometrics\, weight training\, and high intensity cardio blended for a solid 500-1000 calorie burn session. If you are looking for results\, a supportive community\, and a workout built for the most hardcore\, you should visit Aaron! He will show you all the moves to be your sexiest self!\\n\\nwww.aerialyogaschool.com to enter the Sexy Transformation Challenge \\nwww.uppercutboxingsarasota.com for info about taking Aaron Jaco's class"
2022-10-27T19:52:00,464 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-10-27T19:52:00,470 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/226k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,470 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 226k/226k [00:00<00:00, 40.3MB/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,561 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-10-27T19:52:00,562 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/27.0 [00:00<?, ?B/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,562 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 27.0/27.0 [00:00<00:00, 38.7kB/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,603 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-10-27T19:52:00,604 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/666 [00:00<?, ?B/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,605 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 666/666 [00:00<00:00, 593kB/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,650 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-10-27T19:52:00,652 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - encoded_inputs {'input_ids': [101, 1000, 2047, 6768, 1032, 1010, 2238, 5840, 1006, 2019, 2072, 1007, 1024, 2833, 3808, 1998, 4781, 2523, 1997, 2634, 1006, 1042, 11488, 2072, 1007, 5766, 9805, 16425, 21663, 5960, 14360, 2006, 9432, 2056, 2008, 1996, 4311, 7864, 2011, 6768, 1998, 8935, 2024, 3929, 14469, 2096, 2008, 7864, 2011, 15244, 2001, 15884, 1012, 2002, 2036, 2056, 2008, 15244, 2833, 4584, 2024, 2356, 2000, 12040, 2037, 5372, 3189, 1999, 1016, 1011, 1017, 2420, 2051, 1012, 2582, 1032, 1010, 14360, 2056, 2008, 1996, 2833, 2449, 7751, 2323, 2031, 2037, 2219, 3488, 2005, 9361, 1997, 2037, 3688, 2061, 2004, 2000, 4468, 2107, 10876, 2229, 1012, 2002, 2036, 2056, 2008, 1996, 2833, 3808, 12396, 2024, 2356, 2000, 2025, 2069, 3579, 2006, 9089, 2571, 2021, 2036, 2000, 4060, 2039, 8168, 2013, 2060, 8712, 1012, 1000, 1000, 12464, 25256, 1311, 29872, 29870, 29878, 29870, 100, 1326, 29876, 29851, 1325, 29876, 29852, 29871, 29863, 1335, 29877, 29871, 29876, 29875, 29877, 29859, 29871, 29869, 1338, 29870, 29853, 1016, 1325, 29877, 29871, 29874, 1311, 29859, 29868, 29876, 29854, 29876, 29869, 1064, 100, 1064, 1032, 1032, 1050, 1032, 1032, 12835, 7113, 2078, 16686, 3270, 2739, 2003, 2028, 1997, 2087, 3427, 18388, 2739, 3149, 1012, 1032, 1032, 1050, 1032, 1032, 18699, 7869, 2017, 2064, 3422, 2444, 18388, 2739, 1032, 1010, 4911, 2739, 1032, 1010, 4331, 2739, 1032, 1010, 6745, 2739, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
2022-10-27T19:52:00,605 [WARN ] W-model-1-stderr com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 666/666 [00:00<00:00, 593kB/s]
2022-10-27T19:52:00,650 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 
2022-10-27T19:52:00,652 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - encoded_inputs {'input_ids': [101, 1000, 2047, 6768, 1032, 1010, 2238, 5840, 1006, 2019, 2072, 1007, 1024, 2833, 3808, 1998, 4781, 2523, 1997, 2634, 1006, 1042, 11488, 2072, 1007, 5766, 9805, 16425, 21663, 5960, 14360, 2006, 9432, 2056, 2008, 1996, 4311, 7864, 2011, 6768, 1998, 8935, 2024, 3929, 14469, 2096, 2008, 7864, 2011, 15244, 2001, 15884, 1012, 2002, 2036, 2056, 2008, 15244, 2833, 4584, 2024, 2356, 2000, 12040, 2037, 5372, 3189, 1999, 1016, 1011, 1017, 2420, 2051, 1012, 2582, 1032, 1010, 14360, 2056, 2008, 1996, 2833, 2449, 7751, 2323, 2031, 2037, 2219, 3488, 2005, 9361, 1997, 2037, 3688, 2061, 2004, 2000, 4468, 2107, 10876, 2229, 1012, 2002, 2036, 2056, 2008, 1996, 2833, 3808, 12396, 2024, 2356, 2000, 2025, 2069, 3579, 2006, 9089, 2571, 2021, 2036, 2000, 4060, 2039, 8168, 2013, 2060, 8712, 1012, 1000, 1000, 12464, 25256, 1311, 29872, 29870, 29878, 29870, 100, 1326, 29876, 29851, 1325, 29876, 29852, 29871, 29863, 1335, 29877, 29871, 29876, 29875, 29877, 29859, 29871, 29869, 1338, 29870, 29853, 1016, 1325, 29877, 29871, 29874, 1311, 29859, 29868, 29876, 29854, 29876, 29869, 1064, 100, 1064, 1032, 1032, 1050, 1032, 1032, 12835, 7113, 2078, 16686, 3270, 2739, 2003, 2028, 1997, 2087, 3427, 18388, 2739, 3149, 1012, 1032, 1032, 1050, 1032, 1032, 18699, 7869, 2017, 2064, 3422, 2444, 18388, 2739, 1032, 1010, 4911, 2739, 1032, 1010, 4331, 2739, 1032, 1010, 6745, 2739, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
2022-10-27T19:51:58.086:[sagemaker logs]: MaxConcurrentTransforms=1, MaxPayloadInMB=50, BatchStrategy=MULTI_RECORD
2022-10-27T19:52:01,360 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - prediction_output.tolist() tensor([[0.9766, 0.0234]], device='cuda:0')
2022-10-27T19:52:01,360 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Preprocess time - 0.04482269287109375 ms
2022-10-27T19:52:01,361 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Predict time - 951.9212245941162 ms
2022-10-27T19:52:01,361 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Postprocess time - 1.8284320831298828 ms
2022-10-27T19:52:01,362 [INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 956
2022-10-27T19:52:01,362 [INFO ] W-9000-model ACCESS_LOG - /169.254.255.130:37830 "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
2022-10-27T19:52:01,360 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - prediction_output.tolist() tensor([[0.9766, 0.0234]], device='cuda:0')
2022-10-27T19:52:01,360 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Preprocess time - 0.04482269287109375 ms
2022-10-27T19:52:01,361 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Predict time - 951.9212245941162 ms
2022-10-27T19:52:01,361 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Postprocess time - 1.8284320831298828 ms
2022-10-27T19:52:01,362 [INFO ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 956
2022-10-27T19:52:01,362 [INFO ] W-9000-model ACCESS_LOG - /169.254.255.130:37830 "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
```

Comment: The split is correct if you want to take each line of your csv as a single sentence. To then tokenize the sentence, you have to manipulate the batch. In order to answer, can you edit the question by inserting the code of the inference script? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, just did. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I can't reproduce the code in this form. When you try to print input_data inside predict_fn(), does it print one line at a time or all 3 at once? In the first case then we can work on the job configuration, in the second case we need to investigate the tokenizer.

Comment: It prints all three at once. Furthermore, If I try and index the printed input at say indice 0, I get the char "j" instead of "joe annes rifle accesories discount". This tells me that the object seems to be all three sentences put into one string, instead of three separate strings, which is how they should be

Comment: Can you upload CloudWatch logs of the batch transform execution on a single instance? I'd like to see what comes out of the prints you put in. The configurations are right, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: just posted some of the logs. Were you able to run a batch transform, where the data was in a CSV, and strategy="MultiRecord"? If so, when you ran the batch transform on multiple string value inference examples, were you able to index the actual inference examples, thus being able to properly use the huggingface tokenizer?

Answer (score 0):

In the SageMaker TensorFlow container I created a numpy array of the input that then allows me to access each record. I suspect you can do something similar in the HuggingFace container.

For example,

```
def read_csv(csv):
    return np.array([[float(j) for j in i.split(",")] for i in csv.splitlines()])


def input_handler(data, context):
    """Pre-process request input before it is sent to TensorFlow Serving REST API
    Args:
        data (obj): the request data stream
        context (Context): an object containing request and configuration details
    Returns:
        (dict): a JSON-serializable dict that contains request body and headers
    """

    if context.request_content_type == "text/csv":

        payload = data.read().decode("utf-8")
        inputs = read_csv(payload)

        input = {"inputs": inputs.tolist()}

        return json.dumps(input)
```

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_batch_transform/custom_tensorflow_inference_script_csv_and_tfrecord/custom_tensorflow_inference_script_csv_and_tfrecord.ipynb